# how to update all records with updateAttributes in postgres sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to update all records meet our criteria with `updateAttributes` in postgres sequelize.

```
deactivateJobsByCompany(companyData.id, {transaction: t}).then(function(jobs) {
    jobs.updateAttributes({is_active: false}, {transaction: t}).then(function () {
        onSuccess(company);
    })
});
```

I don't know why `jobs.updateAttributes` got error. Please let me know how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the update method, something like

```
Model.jobs.update({is_active:false},
{where:{company_id:Id}})
```

Also updateAttributes works on an model instance, is the `jobs` returned by 
`deactivateJobsByCompany` a model instance

If it returns an array of jobs, you might need to call `updateAttributes` on each of them.